# Cannot use eclipse for android programming after installing Team Explorer

Tags: android

Hy guys.I have a little problem.Yesterday i uploaded my android app to TFS(Team Foundation Server) and now i can't run the app as android project anymore.I can't add android activities anymore or even create an android project.Basically i cannot do anything related to android.Any ideas?

Comment: Try deleting your emulators for one... Also...how does it behave, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: i can only run the project as Java Applet,Java Application and JUnit Test,and as i said i cannot do anything related to android.I don't have any errors or something,that's why i don't really know what to do.I think eclipse see the project as a normal java project(maybe some settings have been reset,i really don't know what is happening)

Comment: If you can't create a new Android Project, then your problem must be related to the Android SDK. Check if it's up and running, check if the path to it is correct by going to Prefferences (should have a tab there Android) and check if the install path is correct. Also, try deleting the app from Eclipse (NOT FROM DISK) and then Import, existing projects and see how that works out.

Comment: The SDK was indeed the problem,eclipse didn't recognize  it anymore for some reason. I've  downloaded again the ADT Bundle and everything works fine.all i need to do is to install again Team Explorer and hope it won't do any damage anymore. Thx for help.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck coding!